# Laravel 5.6 AJAX живой поиск

Tags: ajax, laravel

Пытаюсь создать живой поиск по модели User. Проблема в том что AJAX возвращает пустой массив данных, не могу понять в чем проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста)

Код контроллера

```
public function AjaxUsers(Request $request)
      {
          $text_input = $request->input('text_input');
          $users = User::all()->where('fio','like' ,'%'.$text_input.'%');
          return response()->json($users);
      }
```

Код AJAX

```
$('.search-user').bind("change keyup input click", function(){
            if($(this).val().length >= 2){
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "{{url('admin/bd/roles/AjaxUsers')}}", 
                    data: {text_input:$(this).val(), _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
                                success: function(data) {
                                   $(".search-result").html(data).fadeIn(); 
                                   console.log(data);
                             }
                     });
                 }
        });
```

Comment: Если убираю WHERE то AJAX возвращает все записи, а LIKE не хочет(

Comment: Так тоже возвращает пустой массив `$users = User::where('fio','like' ,'%{$text_input}%')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто.

```
public function AjaxUsers(Request $request)
{
    $text_input = $request->input('text_input');
    $users = User::where('fio','like' ,"%{$text_input}%")->get(); // кавычки двойные!
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

Comment: Вот где об этом написано?! Всю документацию перерыл по ларавелу, ни где этого нет. Спасибо огромное!!!!! Помогло)

Comment: Ну я документацию несколько раз перечитывал и постоянно ей пользуюсь, все время находя новое. А также очень помогает изучение исходного кода понять, как работает тот или иной метод.

Comment: В первом случае (в вопросе) - метод `Model::all()` вытаскивает все записи из таблицы и возвращает коллекцию моделей.
Во втором случае (в комментарии) класс модели проксирует статический метод where на объект билдера, у которого есть метод `get()` для получения результатов из базы по указанным условиям. Все бы получось, если бы не одинарные кавычки (а это уже не `laravel`, а знание языка)

Comment: Спасибо за консультацию. а подскажите еще, пожалуйста, почему в .search-result у меня выводиться одна последняя запись, хотя ajax в консоль возвращает 3 модели по запросу "ши". `$.ajax({ method: 'POST',
 url: "{{url('admin/bd/roles/AjaxUsers')}}", //Путь к обработчику
data: {text_input:$(this).val(), _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},success: function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index, data){
$(".search-result").html(data.fio).fadeIn();
console.log(data);
});
 }
 });`

Comment: Блин, в комментарии без форматирования сложно читать код.
Но суть в том, что ты во все элементы `.search-result` при каждой итерации вставляешь имя. Вот и будет тебе результат последней итерации. Сначала сформируй html (или новые объекты jQuery), а потом вставляй их в нужное место (желательно единственное)